# Practical uses of Flash IK classes (IKArmature, IKBone, IKJoint, IKMover)

Tags: flash, inverse-kinematics

Are there practical examples of the Flash Inverse Kinematics Classes (IKArmature, IKBone, IKJoint, IKMover?)

I have seen examples on the web of how to use these classes, but I am not sure where they would come into use...it seems more straightforward to just use the Bone Tool to add bones, then use poses to pose your doll, and then use frame labels to animate to the poses.

That, or, use the bone tool and then switch to "runtime" to make your bones interactive.

Answer (score 0):

It's just like any other tool in Flash really, if you have a use for it, use it.

We used it on the homepage of [Strange & Dawson](http://strangeanddawson.com/) because we wanted a robot arm... so it's a natural fit. Do this animation without using IK would have been a nightmare or at least involved preset animations. IK let us control the arm dynamically to have a more organic behaviour.

That said, it's still pretty buggy so it can be a struggle coding against armature but have some fun with it and see what uses your imagination can come up with!

Comment: But you can use the bone tool to pose and animate a robot arm *without* using IK classes, can you explain a bit further about why/how you used these classes?

Comment: IK gets pretty messy, pretty quickly. If you want to move multiple joints that are connected, there's a lot of logic and complex maths that goes into figuring out where the other joints and bones need to go. Flash's IK classes does that work for you so you only need to animate the end point and let the IKMover figure out the rest.